# Warning image in Gparted

Tags: gparted

Suddenly I have got a warning symbol (at /dev/sda2 partition) in my gparted display.

[image: Image of the Gparted window.]

What does it mean? What's wrong with my HDD? Help me correct it.

Comment: right click on the drive and click properties

Comment: you can't do nothing with that until you remove the exclamatory mark. Just check for bad-blocks.

Comment: @sbergeron: You should write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally that symbol just means there was a problem accessing the data within the partition, either because of an unsupported filesystem or some other issue. Try right clicking on the partition and then clicking on "Information"

Comment: Just an extra tip, I recently backed up my hard drive, and got this error. What helped me is reconnecting the drive.

Answer (score 1):

An exclamation mark beside a partition means that GParted encountered a problem when reading the partition.  With NTFS the most common problem is that Windows was not shut down properly and that the NTFS file system is in an inconsistent state.  An inconsistent NTFS file system can be fixed often by just booting into Windows (Windows should automatically run "chkdsk" on the partition) and then using the menu option Start -> Shutdown.  If that doesn't work, you can also run "chkdsk /f /r"  on the drive letter for the partition from a Windows command prompt and then reboot into Windows twice.

Comment: It is not working for me.

Answer (score -3):

What you are seeing is just an indication that this partition does not yet contain a filesystem. Right clicking on the line that shows the exclamation point in a red circle will bring up a context menu that allows selection of a filesystem to format the partition with.