# Extending Harddisk space

Tags: partitioning, disk

Ok,so i had installed ubuntu on my hp laptop by completely removing windows 8.1.now the problem is that i have 500gb of disk space originally and ubuntu has used up arond 80 gb of it.I cannot access the remaining 420 gb now i.e it cannot be seen from my ubuntu desktop.please help as i want to change the 80gb to the whole of 500gb.

Comment: Install gparted in Ubuntu using the Software Center. Run gparted and take a screenshot showing your drive's partitions. Upload the image in imgur.com and edit your question above and add a link to the image. This will help us understand the situation better. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/491350/warning-image-in-gparted as an example.

Answer (score 0):

boot a livecd, open gparted then resize the 80gb partition to use the entire disk

Comment: I gained points from this yet it has 0 upvotes. Who downvoted this? It was a completely honest answer!