# Gparted can not list disk percentage usage (Ubuntu 16.04 )

Tags: hard-drive, gparted

I have a hybrid hard disk :

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SandForce Driven SSDs
Device Model:     KINGSTON SV300S37A240G
User Capacity:    240.057.409.536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS, ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Apr 19 12:51:20 2018 -03
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

**-dev/sdb is shown partitions and percentage available**

**-but dev/sda has no info about disk usage**

Getting some info :

```
e2label: Filesystem has unsupported feature(s) while trying to open /dev/sda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
dumpe2fs: Filesystem has unsupported feature(s) while trying to open /dev/sda
```

---

Não foi possível ler o conteúdo deste sistema de arquivos!
Por isso, algumas operações podem ficar indisponíveis.
A causa pode ser um pacote de software ausente.
A seguinte lista de pacotes é requerida para suporte ao ext4 sistema de arquivos:  e2fsprogs v1.41+.

Google Translate from **Ubuntu Portuguese**:

> Could not read the contents of this file system! Therefore, some
>   operations may be unavailable. The cause may be a missing software
>   package. The following list of packages is required to support the
>   ext4 file system: e2fsprogs v1.41 +.

---

After try `gparted` live is possible to read partitions correctly.

[image]

GParted live show info (gparted-live-0.31.0-1-amd64)

[image]

```
sudo parted -l

Modelo: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
Disco /dev/sda: 240GB
Tamanho do setor (lógico/físico): 512B/512B
Tabela de Partição: loop
Opções de disco: 

Número  Início  Fim    Tamanho  Sistema de arquivos  Opções
1      0,00B   240GB  240GB    ext4


Modelo: ATA SanDisk SSD i100 (scsi)
Disco /dev/sdb: 24,0GB
Tamanho do setor (lógico/físico): 512B/512B
Tabela de Partição: msdos
Opções de disco: 

Número  Início  Fim     Tamanho  Tipo      Sistema de arquivos  Opções
 1      1049kB  300MB   299MB    primary   fat32                boot, esp
 2      301MB   24,0GB  23,7GB   extended
 6      301MB   22,0GB  21,7GB   logical   ext4
 5      22,0GB  24,0GB  2000MB   logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Please translate your posts' content to english!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Google Portuguese translation services used above.

Comment: What does `apt-cache show e2fsprogs` reveal?

Comment: What is on sda? If Windows is fast start up off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Linux NTFS driver will not mount hibernated NTFS. Or is /home encrypted? If you right click on red ! what does it say?

Comment: @oldfred good eye there! I didn't even notice the red `!` in the lower left of the screen shot.

Comment: Is this a brand new drive or have you installed programs/data on it previously?

Comment: @oldfred e2label: Filesystem has unsupported feature(s) while trying to open /dev/sda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
dumpe2fs: Filesystem has unsupported feature(s) while trying to open /dev/sda

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix there is no windows ,ntfs ,etc .

Comment: Notice that using gparted live show correct info from hard disks . Seems to be something related to e2label version

Comment: Was drive blank from vendor or do you have some unique partitioning or format. Or did you use drive as installer, but I think gparted would even see it if configured as hybrid DVD/flash type format for installer.

Comment: @oldfred /dev/sdb2 has /  ext4 , Swap and /dev/sdb1 /boot/efi  fat32 . /dev/sda has just /home . It is not a new drive , maybe 1 year or more using it .

Comment: Is /home just sda, or is it partition sda1? Directly using drive without partition is not recommended and may lead to all sorts of issues. Drive is then a "super" floppy when it has not partitions. So standard ways to mount, repair or see drive are not the same. Try this, but not sure it will work on a drive like sda, but if sda1 should work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: @oldfred those kind of hybrid drive are like splited in 2 , SSD is sdb in this case 22 giga , the HDD is sda , so i dont know system see it , as separeted drive or something different . Notice that fisically it is one device .

Comment: Is it just a hybrid drive or Intel SRT (or similar) where the SSD is used just for the Windows hiberfile for booting? That may not show unless drive settings are AHCI, not Intel SRT.

Comment: Regular drive , where the point is to have SSD to install operating system and get better performance , the HDD is used for user storage . But it is not necessary to use it this way.

Comment: Looks like that filesystem uses new features that were not supported by the ext2/3/4 tools that came with Ubuntu 16.04 two years ago. As it works in a recent GParted Live, it would probably also work with GParted on Ubuntu 18.04.  Could you test that with a new Ubuntu 18.04 live image?

Comment: Ping @Fabby in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) when you wake up and I'll have a session with you, because it's unclear what you want: use the SSD as cache or as an actual drive. (a hybrid hard drive can do both)

Answer (score 3):

To help alleviate some of the confusion. The KINGSTON SV300S37A240G is not a hybrid drive. It's a [stand alone SSD.](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/sv300s3_us.pdf) I agree with [oldfred.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026688/gparted-can-not-list-disk-percentage-usage-ubuntu-16-04#comment1674374_1026688) It appears that a filesystem was placed on /dev/sda without a partition table of any kind. This explains why gparted shows /dev/sda without any partition numbers.  You can confirm this from the terminal with the command  `sudo parted -l` which will normally provide output similar to this and will allow you to confirm whether or not you actually have a /dev/sdb:

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA THNSNH12 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  13.3GB  13.3GB  primary  ext4
 2      13.3GB  128GB   115GB   primary  ext4         boot


Model: ATA WDC WD2003FZEX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ext4


Model: ATA WDC WD3001FAEX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  3000GB  3000GB  ext4
 2      3000GB  3001GB  1074MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

`

If the drive has been wiped you'll get output like this:

```
Error: /dev/sdd: unrecognised disk label
Model: JetFlash Transcend 4GB (scsi)                                      
Disk /dev/sdd: 4014MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

If the entire device has been formatted with a file-system and no partition table you'll get output like this:

```
Model: JetFlash Transcend 4GB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 4014MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  4014MB  4014MB  ext4
```

**Edit:**
Note that [parted will report "loop" when it can't find a partition table.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166597/67643)

The red dot with the exclamation point indicates a problem reading the  file-system which is why you aren't getting any usage data. That warning is well explained here: [Warning image in Gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491350/warning-image-in-gparted)

The root cause (of that) could be anything from a dodgy connection to badblocks. The command `cat /var/log/syslog | grep sda` should provide some clues in your case.

All the above command does is provide output matching the device sda from your syslog.

**EDIT:**

as `e2fsprogs` is [essential] I'm relatively certain that you have it and that it's version 1.41+ you can always check to be sure.
The command `dpkg -l e2fsprogs` will produce that information for you as in this example:

> ii  e2fsprogs 1.42.13-1ubuntu1   amd64  ext2/ext3/ext4 file system utilities

This output tells me that as of this date I have the most current version of e2fsprogs for 16.04 installed thats currently [available in the repositories.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/e2fsprogs)

Your question doesn't indicate whether or not you have critical data on /dev/sda but if you do, you might wish to consider making a backup image of the drive, loop mounting that image and then attempting to [Rewrite the superblock and group descriptors only.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/recovering-ext4-superblocks) For safety, I highly recommend working with an image rather than the hardware when attempting data recovery.

Comment: I added some more info  with parted -l to the question , seems that /dev/sda is not shown , /dev/sdb yes with partition table msdos .

Comment: +1. I admit I haven't really be following this thread but shouldn't your answer have a recommendation at the end to use `gparted` to wipe the partition and create a new one properly in it's place?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix a recommendation as to a course of action requires an understanding of the root cause, hence the suggestion to grep syslog for information about the device in question. If it's a dodgy cable we would see connection issues and replacing it would do the trick. If there's info regarding smart failures replacing the drive itself would be a good idea.  I don't think it's prudent to recommend wiping data when there's still a possibility of recovery.

Comment: @EliasAlves both drives are shown in your recent edit. sda formatted with an ext4  filesystem and no partition table as well as your 24GB Sandisk SSD with a partition table, a boot partition and an extended partition containing a logical ext4 and a logical swap partition. I hope this helps. Cheers! ;-)

Comment: @ElderGeek you are right , but why does it have a partition table : loop ? And why gparted live display right info ?

Comment: @EliasAlves for the former, updated answer. For the latter, help about will show you what version your installed gparted is as well as your gparted live. [The current version of gparted live appears to be 0.31](https://gparted.org/download.php) while the version in the repositories is 0.25. I don't closely track the gparted project but details on the latest round of changes/bug fixes can be found [here](https://gparted.org/news.php). Cheers!

Comment: @ElderGeek I already had put gparted live version Before image . But forgot to describe gparted installed (as you said 0.25)

Comment: @EliasAlves Always [eager to help.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16264/are-we-truly-eager-to-help)